# Trim objects from array where "I.active = false"

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas

How would I remove any object from my array `notafications` where `I.active = false`?

**Clarification:** 
I am basically trying to have a certain object in the array "mark itself for deletion" once it performs what it needs to.

I push the parameters to the array with this code:

```
notafications.push(notafication({
    font: "60px pong",
    baseline: "top",
    align: "left",
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    text: "this is a test",
    x: 100,
    y: 100
}));
```

Then this function does its logical voodoo to it:

```
function notafication(I) {
I.active = true;
I.render = true;
I.count = 3;
I.flashTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (!pingpong.paused) {
        I.count--;
        if (I.count%2 == 1) {
            I.render = true;
        }
        else {
            I.render = false;
        }
        if (I.count == 0) {
            clearInterval(I.flashTimer);
            I.render = false;
            I.active = false;
        }
    }
},750);
return I;
}
```

And finally, here is the notification rendering segment of my gameloop.

```
if (render.notafication) {
    notafications.forEach(function notafication(I) {
        ctx.font = I.font;
        ctx.textAlign = I.align;
        ctx.textBaseline = I.baseline;
        ctx.fillStyle = I.color;
        if (I.render) {
            ctx.fillText(I.text,I.x,I.y);
        }
    });
}
```

**Note:**
Yes, I know I have notification spelled wrong in my code. I've just continued to spell it wrong on purpose until this portion of the code is done. Then I'll find-replace it to the correct spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So much for needing help with this. I figured out the solution.

I simply added this bit of code to my gameloop:

```
notafications = notafications.filter(function notafication(I) {
    return I.active;
});
```

Hopefully this will be of use to someone in the future.

Comment: Aauuugghhhhh please fix the spelling now, it is destroying my mind!